# DisabledIF - MFORM fields

Tags: moodle

```
Moodle V2.9 

// Enrolment duration

$mform->addElement('duration', 'enrolperiod', get_string('enrolperiod', 'enrol_self'), array('optional' => true, 'defaultunit' => 86400));
$mform->addHelpButton('enrolperiod', 'enrolperiod', 'enrol_self');

// Notify before enrolment expires

$options = array(0 => get_string('no'), 1 => get_string('expirynotifyenroller', 'core_enrol'), 2 => get_string('expirynotifyall', 'core_enrol'));
$mform->addElement('select', 'expirynotify', get_string('expirynotify', 'core_enrol'), $options);
$mform->addHelpButton('expirynotify', 'expirynotify', 'core_enrol');
$mform->disabledIf('expirynotify', 'enrolperiod');
```

**Enrolment duration** has a default enable checkbox. 
I wanted to enable **Notify before enrolment expires** unless **enrolment duration** is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `duration` field is a group of fields

- A `text` field named `number`
- A `select` field named `timeunit`
- A `checkbox` field named `enabled`

See `/lib/form/duration.php`

So maybe try

```
$mform->disabledIf('expirynotify', 'enrolperiod[enabled]', 'notchecked');
```